# where to put click listeners in mvvm android

Tags: android, mvvm, sharedpreferences

I am trying to follow MVVM design pattern in my android projects, but I faced some problems:
 1. I don't know where to put click listeners, put it into the ViewModel or into the view if the action is to transport to another activity/fragment or doing some logic without redirecting to another view
 2. I knew that shared preference will be put into the model but create a separate class to all shared preference only or put it into the model class example: in login, I want to save username & password does I make my shared preference functions in UserModel or make a new class and name it SharedPreference ??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

1. Put the on click listeners in your activity/fragment and not in the view-model as listeners are still part of the view.
2. Shared preference methods should not be called inside the view-model itself, instead, make your view-model call a class that would do the saving of information into the shared preference. In this case, I would recommend using repository pattern. Your view-model will now then call method x() from your repository, and method x() will now then do the saving of information through shared preference, local database or maybe through the cloud.

Comment: If you were to place a click handler inside a viewmodel and the activity got killed, your viewmodel would be holding on to a dead listener and this would be a memory leak.

Answer (score 5):

```
   <Button
       android:id="@+id/btn_nw"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.testLoginModuleClicked()}"
       android:text="Login"/>
```

In ViewModel class

```
val loginClickEvent = SingleLiveEvent<Void>()
fun testLoginModuleClicked() {
    loginClickEvent.call()
}
```

in your activity/fragment class

```
 loginVM.loginClickEvent.observe(this, Observer {
        callMockApi()
    })
```

Comment: Do not call API from an activity or a fragment.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/item_people"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:clickable="true"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:onClick="@{stateViewModel::onItemClick}">

  </LinearLayout>
```

in viewmodel

```
 public void onItemClick(View v){

    }
```

by creating function in view mode you can add click listener.

Next for shared preferenece , create utils file in common.so that you can use it for entire app.

Comment: if the onClick will transport me from current activity to another, put it also in the view model ?? for example back button

Comment: @DineshRaj is that a recipe for disaster? We were told never store context on ViewModel. If I had my Activity/Fragment become the listeners of the View I definitely cannot store this on ViewModel or it will leak. Is that correct?

Comment: where we storing context here? @NeonWarge

Comment: After receiving the click/event in your ViewModel, emit a SingleLiveEvent if you want the view to navigate, then let your view start the navigation.

Comment: actually this is true MVVM way. but google's mvvm is different (probably due to legacy stuff). so they recommend to handle ui listeners directly in the activity/fragment